# Gradle custom plugin task

Tags: gradle, groovy

Tried to understand how to create custom plugins. But I can't get my new task working. I get this error:

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'code4reference']
>
> > No such property: printTask for class: libs.gradle.NewPlugin

But it's working when I run println from NewPlugin class.
There are two groovy files, one for plugin initialization and one for task. They are located:

> /home/boilerplate/boilerPlate/src/main/groovy/libs/gradle/build.groovy

```
package libs.gradle;

import org.gradle.api.*;

apply plugin: NewPlugin

class NewPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.task('myTask', type: printTask)
    }
}
```

> /home/boilerplate/boilerPlate/src/main/groovy/libs/gradle/printTask.groovy

```
package libs.gradle;

import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction

class printTask extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    def showMessage() {
        println '------------showMessage-------------------'
    }
}
```

Implementation:

> /home/boilerplate/boilerPlate/src/main/resources/META-INF/gradle-plugins/code4reference.properties

```
implementation-class=libs.gradle.NewPlugin
```

**Update:**
Now I faced another issue when executing my new task that should sign all RPMs found on path. I know this works just fine when in build.gradle:

```
package libs.gradle;

import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction

class Sign extends DefaultTask {
    def workdir = project.projectDir.getPath()
    @TaskAction
    def showMessage() {
        ext.signfiles = files{
            fileTree(dir: "$workdir").matching{ include 'build/**/*.rpm' }
        }
        doLast {
            signfiles.each{ File file->
                def args = /echo -e "spawn rpm --resign ${file}\nexpect \"Enter pass phrase:\"\nsend \"\\r\"\nexpect" | expect/
                        exec {
                    commandLine 'bash', '-c', "$args"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Could not find method files() for arguments [libs.gradle.Sign$_showMessage_closure1@4bf8b77] on task ':myTask' of type libs.gradle.Sign.

Answer (score 0):

```
ext.signfiles = project.fileTree(dir: "$workdir").matching{ include 'build/**/*.rpm' }
```

But not sure what workdir is.
The exec below should also be

```
project.exec {
                    commandLine 'bash', '-c', "$args"
                }
```